# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' - How to get data from data frame by querying radius from ball tree?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

How to get data by querying radius from ball tree? For example

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import pandas as pd

bt = BallTree(df[['lat','lng']], metric="haversine")

for idx, row in df.iterrow():
    res = df[bt.query_radius(row[['lat','lng']],r=1)]
```

I want to get those rows in df that are in radius `r=1`. But it throws type error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Following the first answer I got index out of range when iterating over the rows

```
5183
(5219, 25)
5205
(5219, 25)
5205
(5219, 25)
5221
(5219, 25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/sa4.py", line 45, in <module>
    df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.iloc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
IndexError: index 5221 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5219
```

And the code is

```
bag_of_words = ['beautiful','love','fun','sunrise','sunset','waterfall','relax']

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    for word in bag_of_words:
        if word in row['caption']:
            df.loc[idx, word] = 1
        else:
            df.loc[idx, word] = 0

bt = BallTree(df[['lat','lng']], metric="haversine")
indices = bt.query_radius(df[['lat','lng']],r=(float(10)/40000)*360)

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    for word in bag_of_words:
        if word in row['caption']:
            print(idx)
            print(df.shape)
            df.loc[idx,word]=len(df.iloc[indices[idx]][df[word]==1])/\
                             np.max([1,len(df.iloc[indices[idx]][df[word]!=1])])
```

Comment: According to the documentation, it looks like you should be passing a 1D array of points - `bt.query_radius(row[['lat','lng']].values.ravel() ,r=1)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, it requires a 2_D array, same as the one passed in the constructor.

Comment: the problem is trying to get rows by putting in an ndarray? Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the BallTree, but the indices returned by it are not used properly for putting it into index.

Do it this way:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    indices = bt.query_radius(row[['lat','lng']].values.reshape(1,-1), r=1)
    res = df.iloc[[x for b in indices for x in b]]
    # Do what you want to do with res
```

This will also do (since we are sending only a single point each time):

```
    res = df.iloc[indices[0]]
```

Explanation:

I'm using scikit 0.20. So the code you wrote above:

```
df[bt.query_radius(row[['lat','lng']],r=1)]
```

did not work for me. I needed to make it a 2-d array by using reshape().

Now `bt.query_radius()` returns array of array of indices within the radius r specified as mentioned in [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.query_radius):

> **ind** : array of objects, shape = X.shape[:-1]
>
> each element is a numpy integer array listing the indices of neighbors of the corresponding point. Note that unlike the results of
>   a k-neighbors query, the returned neighbors are not sorted by distance
>   by default.

So we needed to iterate two arrays to reach the actual indices of the data.

Now once we got the indices, in a pandas Dataframe, `iloc` is the way to access data with indices.

**Update**:

You dont need to query the `bt` each time for individual points. You can send all the `df`  at once to return a 2-d array containing the indices of points within the radius to the point specified that index.

```
indices = bt.query_radius(df, r=1)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    nearest_points_index = indices[idx]
    res = df.iloc[nearest_points_index]
    # Do what you want to do with res
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation of why this is needed?

Comment: @monotonic I have added the explanation. Please let me know if still not clear.

Comment: @monotonic I saw that you added some comment on it regarding index out of range error. But when I came on this page, its not there. Is the problem solved?

Comment: It's solved. it's not really related to this answer. but thanks for checking.